# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) while importing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error while trying to import the file:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1):
  bartt-ssl_requirement (1.4.2) lib/url_for.rb:9:in `url_for_with_secure_option'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:156:in `url_for'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:83:in `url_for'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:818:in `block in html_options_for_form'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:814:in `tap'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:814:in `html_options_for_form'
  client_side_validations (4.2.5) lib/client_side_validations/action_view/form_tag_helper.rb:11:in `html_options_for_form'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:68:in `form_tag'
  app/views/map_fields/_map_fields.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_map_fields__map_fields_html_erb__4421720753810523207_114950960'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:51:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  app/views/contacts/mapper.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_contacts_mapper_html_erb__581327880311440466_115596220'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:143:in `mapper'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  client_side_validations (4.2.5) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rails-dev-tweaks (1.2.0) lib/rails_dev_tweaks/granular_autoload/middleware.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.9.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.9.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `require'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It is showing in following files:

In views/map_fields/_map_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag nil, :id => 'map_fields_form', :method => :post do -%>
```

In controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  require_dependency 'map_fields'
  map_fields :mapper, ['First Name','Last Name', 'Email', 'Notes'], :file_field => :file, :params => [:contact]

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @contact = @user.contacts.create(contact_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.json { render :json => { :notice => 'Contact was successfully created!',:redirect => user_contacts_url} }
        format.html { redirect_to(user_contacts_url(@user), :notice => 'Contact was successfully created!', :type => 'success') }
       else
        format.json { render :json => {:redirect => false} }
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
  def import
    @contact = Contact.new 
  end
    def mapper
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    count = 0

    if fields_mapped?
      mapped_fields.each do |row|
        params[:contact] = {"user_id" => @current_user.id, "firstname" => row[0], "lastname" => row[1], "notes" => row[3], "email" => row[2].try(:strip)}
        contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

        if contact.save
          count = count + 1
        end
      end

      if count > 0
        flash[:notice] = "#{count} Contact(s) created"
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else 
        flash[:notice] = "No contact was created..." 
        redirect_to :action => :index
      end

    else
      @best_row = @rows[1]
      render #here I am getting error.
    end

    rescue MapFields::InconsistentStateError
      flash[:error] = 'Please try again'
      redirect_to :action => :import
    rescue MapFields::MissingFileContentsError
      flash[:error] = 'Please upload a file'
      redirect_to :action => :import
  end
 # followed by some methods and contact_params
end
```

If I am correct nil values are passed here, so that it is showing the error. Please help me.

Comment: Please show your actual error output with backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Rails 4.2.6. [bartt-ssl_requirement](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement) plugin you got installed is not compatible with Rails 4.

From plugin's readme:

> This version of SSL Requirement is only compatible with Rails 3.x